# Selenium testing for beginners

Tags: selenium

I am a manual tester planning to learn Selenium. I have very limited knowledge about Java. What is the best way to start learning and also some one has told me it is better not to learn selenium if you don't have Java experience. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Selenium IDE Firefox plugin: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

The IDE records the user's browser actions and displays them in pseudo-code. It will also export working code to Java with minimal user input. This should be a good place to start as long as the browser testing you're doing is not complex (neg testing, edge cases, etc.).

Once you're familiar enough with the Selenium operations you can bypass the IDE and create automated test scripts directly in Java.